# Set CommandField Select Visibilty from aspx page

Tags: asp.net, commandfield

I want to do something like this with a GridView:

```
<asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" Visible='<%# return Eval("SC_TABLE") %>' />
```

But that doesn't work, coming up with error:

> Databinding expressions are only
>   supported on objects that have a
>   DataBinding event.
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CommandField
>   does not have a DataBinding event.

Is there anyway I can set the visibility from the aspx page?
PS: SC_TABLE exists from the datasource, so nothing wrong from that part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with a TemplateField instead...

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID=SelectButton CommandName="SELECT" Visible='<%# Eval("SC_TABLE") %>' Text="Select" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: +1: I was hoping to do it with CommandField. I already knew of this way, but its still help. Oh well, seems its impossible with CommandField. :(

Comment: Unless someone else can provide a better answer, I will mark this answer as accepted in a afew days.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer at the end of [this post](http://forums.asp.net/p/1236184/2244842.aspx):

Basically, you need to capture the RowCreated event on the DataGrid

OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated"

Then, on the aspx.cs page use the following code to hide controls:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowIndex == 1)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Clear();
    } 
}
```

It works if you have a CommandField in the first column.